# Jquery parent element is hidden with child element on mouseout

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem where the parent list element is being hidden along with the child, when I only want the child to hide on mouseout. Below is my code, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children().stop().show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children().stop().hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: why dont you just put all the children in a div? much simpler $`('#home_children').show();`

Answer (score 1):

I think I might know what the issue is (having the list markup would help).

You're hiding all of the children of the parent list element, which will "hide" the parent element, since it has nothing to display:

```
<div>
    <ul id="home">
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children().stop().show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children().stop().hide();
            console.log(this);
        }
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sK36C/2/

Use Chrome Console or Firebug in Firefox to view the HTML tab for that element after it's hidden, and you'll notice each of the `LI`s for the `UL#home` are `display: none`. There is nothing to display in the `UL`, so it *appears* to have disappeared.

Here's another demonstration where I tell it to skip the `:first` child and hide the rest:

```
<div>
    <ul id="home">
        <li>This is #home text</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children(':not(:first)').stop().show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children(':not(:first)').stop().hide();
            console.log(this);
        }
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sK36C/3/

Note how the first element isn't hidden, and the `UL#home` is still visible.

See: http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: i usually always use `display:none` myself, but wouldnt `visibility:hidden` accomplish the same thing?

Comment: That would just leave a blank spot where the UL was: http://jsfiddle.net/sK36C/4/ I wouldn't imagine this is what the OP wants, but possibly.

Comment: I understand that is the problem, but the question is how do I get around it? I don't only want to not select the first element, I want to not select the element which has just opened

Comment: I'm not following you. If you want the children of an element to hide, and it's a UL, then the parent will "hide" because it has nothing to display. The `:first` was a demo that this was the problem. So what are you trying "to get around"? Still displaying an empty UL element when all the children are hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Better you can have this using simple `CSS`:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul id="home"><p>MENU</p>
        <li>li1</li>
        <li>li2</li>
        <li>li3</li>
        <li>li4</li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#home:hover li{
    display: block;
}

#home li {
 display: none;
}
```

[**Fiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/sK36C/22/)

Incase if you want to try using **jQuery**

When you use jQuery try doing it using [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home p').hover(
        function(e) {
            $(this).parent().children(':not(:first)').toggle();
           ;
        }
    );
});
```

[**Fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/sK36C/21/)